# outputing a vector to screen?

Tags: c++

Hello this is my first question . I am currently trying to output text from a file and output it to the screen.. I am using a vector to store my strings.. I am wondering what functions I could use that would output the vector?

Currently the only function I know that outputs text to the screen is the `TextOut()` funcion. it uses `LPCTSTR`.

If there arnt any better functions how might I go about converting the vector to a `LPCTSTR`?
 or maybe a function that dosn't require constant variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after the @john suggestion

to get a string from a vector of strings like below:

```
string someString = theVector[0];  //get the first string
```

to get a char* from a string like below:

```
const  char* p = someString.c_str();
```

you can pass a char* to `TextOutA` as the `LPCTSTR` parameter.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I don't understand please elaborate

Comment: @johndoe `char* p = someString.c_str();` should not compile, `const char* p = someString.c_str();` does. Neither is going to work if you are using Unicode however. You might need to use `TextOutA` instead of `TextOut`.

Comment: @johndoe The [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) function returns a `const char*`, which you shouldn't be able to assign to a `char*` (discarding `const`). It's like this because `c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal storage of the `string`, which you shouldn't alter with a non-`string` function.